# gcc linker error: undefined reference to `__security_cookie'

Tags: gcc, curl, dll, linker

with `gcc` I want to build a `DLL`, which uses the Curl lib.

After

```
$gcc -shared -o GA_TestLibV11.dll GA_TestLibV11.o GA_TestLibV11.def curllib_static.lib

$ gcc -shared -o GA_TestLibV11.dll GA_TestLibV11.o GA_TestLibV11.def curllib_static.lib -llibws2_32
```

**I get the following warning (which appears many times)**

Warning: .drectve `/manifestdependency:"type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC90.CRT' v
ersion='9.0.21022.8' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3
b'" /DEFAULTLIB:"MSVCRT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecognized

**and the following errors:**

```
curllib_static.lib(./Release/easy.obj):(.text[_win32_init]+0x7): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'

curllib_static.lib(./Release/easy.obj):(.text[_win32_init]+0x41): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: curllib_st
atic.lib(./Release/easy.obj): bad reloc address 0x41 in section `.text[_win32_in
it]'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What else do I have to link to solve these problems?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to link with one of the bufferoverflow.lib libraries,

> **bufferoverflowU.lib**   This library implements functionality for security
> cookie verification that can be used in the user mode and in
> applications that use the Win32 API. Most applications link to this
> library.
>
> **bufferoverflowK.lib**   This library implements the check of a
> security cookie that works in the kernel mode of the operating system.
> Services and subsystems that run in the kernel mode have to be linked
> to this library.
>
> **bufferoverflow.lib**    This library implements
> functionality for security cookie verification that can be used in the
> user mode. However, bufferoverflow.lib is different from
> bufferoverflowU.lib because bufferoverflow.lib can be used in services
> and in applications that do not use the Win32 API.

See more at [You may receive the "Linker tools error LNK2001" error messages when you build source code by using the Win32 Software Development Kit (SDK) or the Windows Server 2003 Driver Development Kit (DDK) for Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=894573).

Alternatively, you will have to rebuild *curl* without the `/GS` compiler switch,

> In Microsoft Visual Studio 2002, a new compiler switch that is named "
> /GS" has been introduced to the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler. When
> the " /GS" switch is set, the compiler injects buffer overrun
> detection code in the compiled code.